# Discord bot to give different tier payday rewards for different roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am attempting to make the bot pay different amounts to different roles.

The problem is no matter what I try to do, it says that the role is undefined.

I have looked up what that means and have tried some of the things that I've found. I added variables for each role trying with the ID, trying with the name. I am very new to JS and I am relatively new to coding in general. I have tried "roles.find" among other things.

I looked on the discord.js website, but it provided no help. The only code blocks for the functions are tiny and they were also ineffective. Below I have listed the portion of the code regarding the payday command.

```js
if (msg === prefix + 'PAYDAY') {
  if (userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].lastPayday != moment().format('w ww')) {
    userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].lastPayday = moment().format('w ww')


    if ([sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741948113568137317") || [sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741949249717141565")) {
      userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].money += 300;
    } else if ([sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741948119104618537") || [sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741950264742903808") || [sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741950268677292042")) {
      userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].money += 600;
    } else if ([sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741948122627833937") || [sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741950731547836437")) {
      userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].money += 900;
    } else if ([sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741948130999795732") || [sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741949251793190927")) {
      userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].money += 1200;
    } else if ([sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741948127828901949") || [sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741948125316644924")) {
      userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].money += 1500;
    } else if ([sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741948126004248657") || [sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741948124297298050")) {
      userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].money += 2000;
    } else if ([sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741949250287697942")) {
      userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].money += 5000;
    } else {
      message.channel.send({
        "embed": {
          title: "Sorry",
          color: 0x1E97C8,
          fields: [{
            name: "You have no job!",
            value: "Get to work, you lazy bum!",
            inline: true,
          }, {
            name: "HAHA",
            value: ":P",
            inline: true
          }]
        }

      })
      userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].lastPayday = moment("1995-12-25");
```

ERROR

````
if ([sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741948113568137317") || [sender.id + message.guild.id].roles.has(Role => Role.id === "741949249717141565" )) {
                                                     

TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\123\Desktop\SpaceBot\app.js:64:54)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\123\Desktop\SpaceBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\123\Desktop\SpaceBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\123\Desktop\SpaceBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\123\Desktop\SpaceBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\123\Desktop\SpaceBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\123\Desktop\SpaceBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\123\Desktop\SpaceBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting the cache object. Use

```js
if (
     message.guild.member(sender) // get GuildMember object
    .roles.cache.has(roleID)) { // Discord v12 uses managers, and thus requires cache object
       // something
    });
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your prompt response! I think that worked, but now guild is not defined. I've tried to fix it on my own, but it didn't work.

This is my latest attempt:
`const guild = new Discord.Guild();

guild.cache.get("735657160964440178");`

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was my mistake. Use ``message.guild.member(sender)`` instead 